# what is the difference between a hilbert space and a riemannian manifold?

Tags: vector-spaces

I understand that a hilbert space is essentially a banach space with a inner product.

A riemannian manifold is defined as (M,g) where M is a differentiable manifold and g is a riemannian metric.

i wasn't able to find a formal definition for the latter and would appreciate any help in differentiating the two.

Comment: A Hilbert space is a vector space. A manifold does not have to be a vector space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold ? Or any Riemannian geometry book; e.g. do Carmo or Lee.  Basically the two are nothing alike except that they both have an inner product somewhere in their definition.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, can't any finite-dimensional Hilbert space naturally be considered as a flat Riemannian manifold whose metric is given by the inner product of infinitesimal vectors?